# Cannot open sqlite database with linqpad, when WITHOUT ROWID is used

Tags: sqlite, linqpad

I cannot open a sqlite database with linqpad, when WITHOUT ROWID is used. Is there a workaround? A newer versions? Are there sources for the "IQ Driver - for MySQL, SQLite, Oracle" so that I can recompile with a more current sqlite3?

Answer (score 0):

(Too late, replying just for "Google airlines landings")

It looks like standard SQLite in Android doesn't support this option.

A custom compiled SQLite works properly, but it requires lot of work.

See related post: [SQLite "WITHOUT ROWID" supported on Android SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203691/sqlite-without-rowid-supported-on-android-sqlite)